# Why does my rig pose change when i render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

i made a rig of some arms and added a pose. But when i hit F12 to render it, it sets back to default. What's the cause of this?

Comment: Does it also go back if you change frames? that would be from an animation moving the rig. The F12 render will always show the keyframed pose for the frame while the viewport will only update if you change frames.

Answer (score 7):

Look for keyframe registrations.  If a pose has been keyframed, rendering will set it to the appropriate, keyframed pose.

Following the render, hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to return to your unregistered, unrendered pose, then try advancing a frame (with mouse over the timeline, hit right arrow.)  Does the pose change?  Then you have registered keyframes.  Register your new pose before rendering, or delete existing keyframes.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because one of the modifiers either has different render settings or is turned off during rendering (the camera symbol of the modifier is greyed out).

The last thing can be that you're rendering a different frame.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the meshes and armature related to the object you want to freeze in the pose mode. Now, in object mode go to `Object > Apply > Visual Geometry to Mesh`. This will solidify your pose into an actual mesh. Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the modifier for the armature before rendering.
I had the same problem and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Going to graph editor and baking the curves did it for me. I think the culprit was the *Noise* modifier, in my case. Go to *Graph Window > Key> Bake Curves*.